# how to reduce usage of HttpSession

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee

In my application, there are many objects in session. Therefore, the size of the `HttpSession` is high for each user who access my application(It is a Employee information management system). I tried to reduce the objects in session and some time, used the `HttpRequest`. How ever still session caries many objects which results that the JVM memory usage is high and slow the server. Therefore I need to reduce the session size.

Any solution for this ? Should I add another server and balance the load or upgrade the RAM size of the  PC or JVM memory upgrade (If I upgrade so, what will happen in future when more users than now use the system, then again should I have to upgrade the memory?) ? 
My supposed solution is to add those object into a caching server which runs in separate server(separate PC) instead of the session.
Please let me know your ideas.

Comment: How much memory do you currently need per session? How much clients does the application have? First you have to pin down your problem. Can't you first try to reduce the data that you're loading into the session? After improving the application it fully depends on the environment. First memory can be increases, after that you can outsource the session storage to a database server. (Redis (fastest), MongoDB, Postgres, MySQL)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I want the session size between 500KB and 1mb and 100 concurrent users. Every thing that could be done to my knowledge already done. If I use a database server, couldn't it be a performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

Should you add another server? - May be. Should you add RAM and give more memory to JVM? - You could. Will it solve the problem? If the problem is in the design, then it might only upto a certain point. My 1st attempt would be to reduce the objects in session. If that's not possible, have a flat model of that object, you know create a thinned down version of your object which has the bare minimum it needs to be meaningful.

If you still think that all that is done and no significant improvement is noticed, then as Marc suggested, you could try scaling out or scaling up depending on your needs and constraints. Alternatively, you could use *Memcached* or again as Marc suggested Redis or Mongo if you're okay with persisting sessions and are willing to take a bit of performance hit. I say a bit because these things *are* real quick.